# gVim display nothing when I open an existing file

Tags: python, vim, windows-10, vim-plugin

When I type `vim hello.py` in the command prompt to open my file the command prompt the gVim editor opens up however it does not display the one line of text contained in the hello.py file. Why is this? I just want to edit the file.

Comment: Start debugging with `dir hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are in the same directory as hello.py?

Otherwise, gVim will open a new buffer called "hello.py", which on save will be written to whatever directory you are currently in.